# SQL Server database is readonly error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012

I am trying to upgrade one of our web application from Windows Server 2003 to a new box with Windows Server 2012. The application allows us to create multiple instances of another application as virtual directories within a website. Its more like we create an instance of a web application on run time for every signup which is customer specific. Each instance consist of SQL server MDF file that it attaches to SQL server.

The problem I am having is that MDF file is from SQL 2008 and system fails to upgrade it to 2012. If I upgrade it manually then system complains that database is in readonly mode. I have already set application pool identity to Network Service account and I believe it should have sufficient rights to attach/read/write the database. I am unable to reproduce the problem on local system where I am using Windows 8 and SQL 2012. Any help would be appreciated.

**Failed to update database "some.MDF" because the database is read-only.**

Answer (score 0):

Network service has not part in readonly database configuration.It could depend from login role.Have you check via ssms if login user has been bind to the database and if its has the right permission.

Take a look to the image below:

[image]

if not you need to setup right configuration for your customer and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get it working was by allow Network Service full control permissions using NTFS folder permission dialog.